# The bundle is invalid with xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I know you already have several posts with this subject but I still could not find the answer to my problem in time to upload my binary. I get the error:

> The bundle is invalid. New apps and updates app submitted to the App Store must be built with public.

...but I'm already using xcode 5.1.1 so do not know why I get this error. How should I proceed?

Comment: You may be using a beta. Download a fresh copy of Xcode, perhaps.

Comment: ok, i'll download xcode again and try

Comment: i'm not using a beta version of xcode.. and now ? when i create my app i create with xcode 5.1, and now I have xcode 5.1.1, is it this problem?